# How to automatically display the new record to a list when a new record is added in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, crud, angular-observable

I'm currently doing an Angular app with CRUD operations and Springboot API as a back end. The problem is when I add a new user, it successfully added but it does not automatically display on the List. It needs to reload the page to show the updated list.

Here's my add-user.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../user';

import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-user',
  templateUrl: './add-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-user.component.css']
})
export class AddUserComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User = new User();
  submitted = false;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  save() {
    this.userService
    .addUser(this.user).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.user = new User();
      this.goToList();
    },
      error => console.log(error));
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.save();
    this.userService.getUserList();
  }

  goToList() {
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }
}
```

here's my user-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../user';
import { UserDetailsComponent } from '../user-details/user-details.component';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.css']
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
  users: Observable<User[]>;
  toUserDetails: UserDetailsComponent;
  refreshUsers = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reloadData();
  }

  reloadData() {
    this.users = this.refreshUsers.pipe(switchMap(_ => this.userService.getUserList()));
    this.refreshUsers.next(true);
  }


  deleteUser(id: number) {
    this.userService.deleteUser(id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.reloadData();
      }, error => console.log(error));
  }

  userDetails(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['details', id]);
  }

  updateUser(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['update', id]);
  }
}
```

and here's my user.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { User } from './user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  user: User[];
  users: BehaviorSubject<User[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  private BASE_URL = environment.apiBaseUrl;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  public getUser(id:number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(`${this.BASE_URL}/users/${id}`);
  }

  public addUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.BASE_URL}/add`, user);
  }

  public updateUser(id: number, value: any): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.put<User>(`${this.BASE_URL}/update/${id}`, value);
  }

  public deleteUser(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.BASE_URL}/delete/${id}`, {responseType: 'text'});
  }

  public getUserList(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.BASE_URL}/users`);
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make use of the `users` property in your `user.service.ts` class definition. Instead of subscribing to the API calls you can use the `users` `BehaviorSubject` and simply update it at the end of each call and subscribe to it.

So you would have something like this:

`user-list.component.ts`

```
//...
reloadData() {
  this.users = this.refreshUsers
    // so instead of rerunning the get user list function you can just get the list
    .pipe(switchMap( _=> this.userService.users));
  this.refreshUsers.next(true);
}
//...
```

Now you just need to make sure that `user.service.ts` updates the list
with each API response.

`user.service.ts`

```
//...
export class UserService {
  user: User[];
  users: BehaviorSubject<User[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  private BASE_URL = environment.apiBaseUrl;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  public getUser(id:number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(`${this.BASE_URL}/users/${id}`)
      .pipe(map((user) => {
        this.user.push(user);
        this.users.next(this.user);

        return user;
      }));
  }

  public addUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.BASE_URL}/add`, user)
      .pipe(map((user) => {
        this.user.push(user);
        this.users.next(this.user);

        return user;
      }));
  }


  // With this function you would find the user and update them but this might
  // be inefficient, so what I would suggest is to use a Record<string, User> type
  // instead of User[] to keep your users then it makes the work easier.
  public updateUser(id: number, value: any): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.put<User>(`${this.BASE_URL}/update/${id}`, value);
  }

  // The case of deleteUser is the same here as well
  public deleteUser(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.BASE_URL}/delete/${id}`, {responseType: 'text'});
  }

  public getUserList(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.BASE_URL}/users`)
      .pipe(map((users) => {
        this.user = users;
        this.users.next(this.user);

        return users;
      }));
  }

}
```

With this you will not be making too many unecessary requests since you have
created a small data cache for your users.

For cases like this I typically use [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/). I would definitely
say check this out, it will provide much better solutions going forward with
this.

Comment: Your answer works in my project. Thank you sir.